# Complex LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, linq-to-entities

Switching to linq is getting much harder.I know I have to use Group by but I don't know how to use it in LINQ to Entities.already took me 3 hours.I have 4 Tables that are Tbl_Products,Tbl_Orders,Tbl_OrderDetail,Tbl_OrderStatus.

Now I want to get This result for each OrderID that belongs to a specific Email Address.

OrderID
TotallAmount of goods
TotallPrice (Must be retrieved from Tbl_Products)
RefOrderID
Any Ideas?

Thanks in Advance!!!
[image: My Entity Model]

Comment: Consider changing your naming structure, so that each table name doesn't start with `Tbl_`. If you can't do that in the database, at least change the names of your entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need group by here:

```
from order in db.Tbl_orders
where order.Email == email
select new
{
    OrderId,
    TotalAmount = order.Tbl_OrderDetail.Sum(d => d.Amount),
    TotalPrice = order.Tbl_OrderDetail.Sum(d => d.Tbl_Products.ProductPrice)
}
```

Comment: Thank you That was very thoughtful of you.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps: [How to: Group Data on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896341.aspx)